# Problem with multiple cisco switches in one script

Tags: python, automation, cisco

I have a script that reads the IP addresses from a file, then it telnets correctly to a router designed for telnet to other switches, the other switches do not have network access to outside networks.

Only the first switch is configured, but the loop has outputs that indicate all IPs are checked

I can see in the control router that only the first switch is connected to an configured, even though the prints in the code indicate all IPs in the loop are connected to.

```
import telnetlib

host ="1.1.1.1"
tn=telnetlib.Telnet(host) #TELNET TO CONTROL ROUTER
tn.write(b"\n")
tn.read_until(b"#")

file = open ('myswitches') # FILE HAS IPS OF SWITCHES

for IP in file:
    tn.write(b"telnet " + IP.encode('ascii') + "\n".encode('ascii'))
    print("CONFIGURING SWITCH " + (IP)) #OUTPUT IS SEEN FOR ALL SWITCHES IN LOOP
    tn.write(b"\n")
    tn.write(b"cisco\n")
    tn.write(b"cisco\n")
    tn.write(b"configure terminal\n")
    tn.write(b"VLAN 88\n")
    tn.write(b"NAME PYTHON_VLAN88\n")
    tn.write(b"end\n")
    tn.write(b"\n")
    tn.write(b"\n")
    tn.write(b"quit\n")

print("END OF SCRIPT")
```

Comment: Do the routers respond with anything after you send the `quit\n` command? Just a guess but you may need to `read_until` that response.

Comment: Thanks @selcuk I just tried a read_until after the quit\n, the result was that 3 of 5 switches were configured, it seems the script works way too fast for the Control Router to apply the configurations.